# adding ListView items with user input from AlertDialog

Tags: android, listview, button, alert, android-alertdialog

im trying to fill a ListView with input from a AlertDialog which open an EditText in it. My problem is every time i give something in the AlertDialog with the EditText and click on my add button from the AlertDialog it fills all the 20 sets of my Array with the same String.But i want the he fill the String from the EditText only 1 time and i can work futher with this 1 item.

here is my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int DIALOG_ALERT = 10;

    ListView list;
    Button addBtn;
    EditText input;

    String[] items;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addPlanBtn);

        input = new EditText(this);

        items = new String[20];

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);



        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alert.setTitle("Train plan name");
                alert.setMessage("enter a name:");
                alert.setView(input);




                alert.setButton("add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            String value = input.getText().toString();

                            for(int i=0; i < items.length; i++){     
                                items[i] = value;

                            }

                     }
                  });

                    alert.show();
            }


        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addPlanBtn"
         >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addPlanBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="add a new Plan" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This for loop in your on click listener is setting the string for all of the members of your array that underlies your list:

```
for(int i=0; i < items.length; i++){     
    items[i] = value;
}
```

To change just the string in question you'll want to index a particular member of the array, e.g.:

```
items[0] = value;
```

That will change only the first item. In your case, the dialog that you pull up isn't tied to a specific list item, so you'll have to come up with a way of keeping track of which list item is being edited.

Comment: ah ok i did this items[which] = value;  but the app crashes than completly

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I had the wrong thing for the working bit of code. I misread your code slightly.

In your case, you don't have the button tied to a particular member of the array. I'm going to edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @atr I give you props for jumping into android dev but it seems like you still have some basic concepts of programming in general that you need to brush up on. If you have an array of items[i] and you try to set a value "which" that is just the argument from the onClick method, that "which" is a number 1, 2, 3 etc. If your items[i] array doesn't have a size of 3, and you try to set items[3], it will crash.

Comment: @Rubber Mallet ye you are completly right, i have a lot to learn. Thank you for explanation, i got it now :-)

Comment: @qzikl thank your for the fast help,but if i do it like this i cant add a second and third and... item. i think my text/meaning wasnt that good explained by me

Comment: That's what I meant by saying that you need a way to keep track of this. In your current code, your button isn't tied to the list, so there is no way of determining which list item is supposed to be edited.

Comment: ahhh ok, thank you. Then i going to look for an other solution

Answer (score 0):

got it,

here is the working code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int DIALOG_ALERT = 10;

    ListView list;
    Button addBtn;
    EditText input;

    String[] items;
    MyListAdapter adapter;
    AlertDialog alert;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addPlanBtn);

        input = new EditText(this);

        items = new String[1];





        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Train plan name");
        alert.setMessage("enter a name:");
        alert.setView(input);


        alert.setButton("add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String value = input.getText().toString();

                    items[items.length - 1] = value;

                    adapter = new MyListAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                    String[] temp = new String[items.length +1];

                    for(int i = 0; i< items.length; i++)
                        temp[i] = items[i];

                    items = temp;

                    alert.dismiss();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             }

          });




        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    alert.show();
            }


        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**MyListAdapter**

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
    }

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
        textView.setText(values[position]);

        return rowView;
      }


}
```

**row_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:textSize="40px" >

    </TextView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addPlanBtn"
         >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addPlanBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="add a new Plan" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you all, who got the time to help me.